# R package AzureGraph | error in function call_graph_enpoint: what is argument "operation"?

Tags: r, microsoft-graph-api, azure-api-apps

I'm using AzureAuth and AzureGraph to pull the CallRecords API from Graph. I'm using an existing app registration. I can retrieve the token, but my script fails with the call_graph_url function.

The problem seems to be the parameter operation, which is required, but for which I cannot find any example in the vignettes of the package or in the Microsoft documentation.

Here is my code so far:

```
library(AzureAuth)
library(AzureGraph)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(rjson)
library(jsonlite)
library(RCurl)


# Create graph login

gr <- create_graph_login()


# App Authentication
AppID <- "XXXXX"
TenantID <- "XXXXXX"
Secret <- "XXXXXX"

App <- gr$get_app(AppID)
service <- App$get_service_principal()

# API Information

Version <- getOption("azure_graph_api_version")
Endpoint <- "https://graph.microsoft.com"

Tok <- AzureAuth::get_azure_token(Endpoint, tenant = TenantID, app = AppID, password = Secret)

EPCall <- call_graph_endpoint(Tok, options = list(), api_version = Version, operation = "CallRecord-PstnCalls.Read.All")
```

See below the error I get:

```
> EPCall <- call_graph_endpoint(Tok, options = list(), api_version = Version, operation = "CallRecord-PstnCalls.Read.All")
Error in process_response(res, match.arg(http_status_handler), simplify) : 
  Bad Request (HTTP 400). Failed to complete operation. Message:
Resource not found for the segment 'CallRecord-PstnCalls.Read.All'.
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) `operation` should be url path `/communications/callRecords/{id}`.

You need to know `id` of `callRecord`. You cannot get all call records.

```
EPCall <- call_graph_endpoint(Tok, options = list(), api_version = Version, operation = "/communications/callRecords/{id}")
```

Comment: Thanks... so it seems I need to use a delta subscription to get the id and the following.  I'm trying to use call_graph_endpoint for the subscription but I can't get to a property that works. Ex: "/communications/callRecords/delta?$select=id&$expand=**call**".